# Apache Camel or any better alternatives on springboot for transformation and routing

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, apache-camel, schema

We have a legacy application that uses SOAP services, hosted as a monolith JBOSS Appserver with spring IOC container exposed to our customers, we are planning a migration to REST and updating the stack to spring boot based microservices.
The key problem is we don't want to change the client SOAP contract and we want to transform the request /response

1. Client SOAP request to our new microservices Rest schema
2. Till the migration is complete keep the routing to old monolith container hosted services
3. As the migration is complete service by service we want to change the routing to the microservices

I was wondering to use Apache camel hosted on a spring boot based container to do the above Job basically behave as an adapter, transformer and router.

Question 1) Is this a good approach or are there any better alternatives out in JAVA, Spring paradigm?

Question 2) Are there any good out of the box Java libraries that can help with schema transformation from i.e SOAP to REST. We can always unmarshall SOAP response and set that on to the REST builders via DTOs but i want to avoid the boiler plate stuff and looking for a more robust solution provided that can easily accomodate any future schema changes?